# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Getting the error as mentioned when I am trying to get the response from API call and display the information in the response object in the template.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined.

In service.ts, I am making a server call. I am using OpenWeatherMap API.

```
getDetails(cityName, countryCd): Observable<any>{
  return this.httpclient.get(`${this.url}${cityName},${countryCd}&APPID=${this.apiKey}`);
}
```

Object format returned by the API:

```
{"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji",
 "coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},
 "country":"JP",
 "cod":"200",
 "message":0.0045,
 "cnt":38,
 "list":[{
    "dt":1406106000,
    "main":{
        "temp":298.77,
        "temp_min":298.77,
        "temp_max":298.774,
        "pressure":1005.93,
        "sea_level":1018.18,
        "grnd_level":1005.93,
        "humidity":87,
        "temp_kf":0.26},
    "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
    "clouds":{"all":88},
    "wind":{"speed":5.71,"deg":229.501},
    "sys":{"pod":"d"},
    "dt_txt":"2014-07-23 09:00:00"}
    ]}
```

In home.component.ts, I am subscribing to the service API call. I am getting the reposnse which is of type 'object'.

I have an array of objects called cities. I am loading the response object from the server as one of the property in each object of the array cities.

```
this.cities = this.cityService.getCities().slice();
this.cities.forEach(element => {
  this.weatherService.getDetails(element.cityName, element.countryCd).subscribe(response => {
    element['cityWeather'] = response;});
});
```

In home.component.html, I am iterating this cities array and the using the response data from the API. The data is displayed properly without any issues. 
But in the console I am seeing an error for every iteration of cities array -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined.

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index">

                <span>{{city.cityWeather.list[0].main.temp | kelvinToCelcius}} &#8451;</span>

                <span>{{city.cityWeather.list[0].wind.speed | mtrPersecToKmPerhr}} km/h</span>

</div>
```

I am relatively new to Angular, need to know what is this error about and how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that in your home component you refer to

```
<span>{{city.cityWeather.list[0].main.temp | kelvinToCelcius}} &#8451;</span>
<span>{{city.cityWeather.list[0].wind.speed | mtrPersecToKmPerhr}} km/h</span>
```

These values may not be defined at all times, so if `city.cityWeather` is undefined, accessing the `.list` property would result in the error

> Cannot read property 'list' of undefined.

You can fix this by using the Angular safe navigation operator (also known as the Elvis operator).

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths
>
> -- [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

By changing `.` to `?.`, Angular will not throw an error if it can't find the property on the object.

**Note that this only works in component templates, and not in TypeScript files.**

Answer (score 2):

You can either use The Angular

> safe navigation operator (?.)

```
city.cityWeather?.list[0]?.main.temp
city.cityWeather?.list[0]?.wind.speed
```

or you can try using Angular async pipe 
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like this:

```html
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index">
        <span>{{city?.cityWeather?.list[0]?.main?.temp | kelvinToCelcius}} &#8451;</span>
        <span>{{city?.cityWeather?.list[0]?.wind?.speed | mtrPersecToKmPerhr}} km/h</span>
    </div>
```

This may be due the fact that your `getCities()` request is completed and your `getDetails()` call is yet to return response which it will give at some point in time due to the asynchronous nature of code. So when the loop execute `cityWeather` is not available and you get the error. The `?` will not throw error but instead it will show data when it will be available.